# How to structure Angular 6 http services?

Tags: angular

Currently, I put every API calls to my backend under one file webService.ts.

But as my API gets more complicated, there will be a lot of routes to request and webServices.ts can be extremely long and hard to manage.

What is a proper way to manage all API call services for a big project?

I am using angular/common/http.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create a `BaseApiService` abstract class that contains the common things, for example:

If you transforms your responses into models, create a method to do it as generic as possible. Remember to generically type this class, use the typescript as your friend.

If you already have many services, will be easy to identify common and repeated code that can be extracted to that class.

This abstract class may contain some constants like api url or some parameters that you may use, like default page size...

Then you create your specific services by extending this class and overriding just the necessary.

Do not use common/http. HttpClient is better and more flexible, it allows using interceptors for example. A nice use for interceptors is appending a header with auth token to all your requests automagically.

There are tons of tips that I can give you, but I'm typing on a mobile. :-D

**Update**

Now that I'm on a computer, take a look on my [ApiProvider](https://gist.github.com/iget-master/ac542c09062b441d9613cb0e2b3354a2), hope it can help you.

Comment: First, I still don't know the use of the abstract class for API calls?
If I just want to http.get some comments from the backend, why don't I just transform it into a model using a pipe since http.get returns an observable? Second, when you say to use HttpClient, do you mean this: import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'? This is from angular.io

Comment: Abstract classes are normal classes that can not be instantiated. You can define empty methods that must be created on the class that extends it. Also you can create non-empty methods too. On your class that extends it, you can override methods.

Comment: Read this doc from typescript docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: And yes. The HttpClient is this one. Also, you can use pipes to transform your data, but to avoid having to always put the pipe. I use the map operator and call a method of my service that handles the conversion and all it details.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a *[generic adapter](https://medium.com/@krishna.acondy/a-generic-http-service-approach-for-angular-applications-a7bd8ff6a068)* to make the GET/POST/PUT requests which would accept the type and the url from other services.

The generic service will be called via the related component services with necessary parameters.

Also i would suggest to use **[`HttpClient.`](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)**

Comment: So, there is not a central file where we put the request URLs and we need to call the urls elsewhere.   
For example, instead of having a function getComments = http.get('localhost/comments) in a webService file, we have a modified function such as getComments('localhost/comments') in our calling file.
Basically, what I asking again is how do you structure urls.

Comment: That should be within the environment.ts , you can load that in each of your services

Comment: So, should I just not having a webService.ts. Instead, I should write a modified HTTP class?

Comment: https://medium.com/@krishna.acondy/a-generic-http-service-approach-for-angular-applications-a7bd8ff6a068

Comment: Just a follow up on that article. It modularize the api services based on the endpoint. For example, we will have a piazzaApiService and BurgerApiService. Is it a good idea to structure so that both of those apiServices are in a shared folder, and I can call them in different components? Or is there a better way to structure this?

Comment: It depends on the way you structure components too, i would recommend you to separate it since it will be easy to manage

Answer (score 0):

We structure our frontend http services to correspond with backend services. So when backend has services like `/api/product` and `/api/transactions` then we have two frontend services: `product.service.ts` and `transactions.service.ts`. Inside those services we have functions which are same as those on the backend side. These services also map the responses from dto's to our frontend model interfaces.

Whenewer is something used by more than 1 module (and it doesn't matter if it is service or component) we put it in shared/common directory.